# how to insert image using ajax in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to upload image in my images folder now my image insert in table but not images folder

Controller.cs

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(student student, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/")
                                                  + file.FileName);
                    student.studentimage = file.FileName;
                }

                InsAjaxEntities.students.Add(student);
                InsAjaxEntities.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><strong>StudentImage:</strong></label>
                    <input type="file" id="studentimage" />
                </div>
            </div>

}
@section scripts {
    <div>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        $('#button').click(function () {
                    

                    var stud = {

                         studentimage: $('#studentimage').val()

                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/Create',
                        data: JSON.stringify(stud),
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            debugger
                            alert('success', data);
                        },
                        error: function (x, y, z) {                           
                            debugger
                        }
                    });
```

table

```
 public string studentimage { get; set; }
```

see my image store this way:

[image]

I am using ajax to store the image in folder but image not store in the folder

my image not store in the folder I want to store in the folder?

how to store image in the folder?

I want to store image in proper path not fake path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-if you want to upload image with ajax you should use FormData like below in java script:

```
 $('#button').click(function () {
                   var data = new FormData();
                    data.append('file',$('#studentimage')[0].files[0]);
                   //add student values too like: data.append('name',$('#name').val());
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/Create',
                        data: data,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (data) {
                            debugger
                            alert('success', data);
                        },
                        error: function (x, y, z) {                           
                            debugger
                        }
                    });
});
```

2- after this change file in your controller should not be null and you can save it proper manner, i suggest creating folder by year and month for that

3- also if you want show image some where you should use

```
function previewFile() {
  const preview = document.querySelector('img');
  const file = $('#studentimage')[0].files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // convert image file to base64 string
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain this line ```$('#studentimage')[0].files[0]``` because not undersand this line what is ```files[0] and $('#studentimage')[0]```  ?

Comment: after you select a file with <input type="file"/> tag, selected file will be added to files prop of that input